# PHP - Live Search using multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've scoured the internet, yet I couldn't find something like my problem. I'm trying to build a live search function that can pull data from multiple tables. It works with one table, but I want to be able to pull from bands, users, (albums, etc.)

Here's my PHP code:

```
require ("includes/config/config.php"); 

$search_term = sanitize(htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

if (!empty($search_term)){

    $search = "(SELECT `band_id`, `band_name` FROM `bands` WHERE `band_name` LIKE '%$search_term%'  LIMIT 0, 5) 
                UNION ALL
                (SELECT `user_id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%$search_term%'  LIMIT 0, 5)";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $search);
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        #$user_id = $row['user_id'];
        #$username = $row['username'];
        $band_id = $row['band_id'];
        $band_name = $row['band_name'];
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);



        if ($check != 0){
            echo "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='index.php?band=$band_id'><li class='searchResults'>" . ucfirst($band_name) . "</li></a>";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='searchResults'>No Results Found</li>";
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#searchbar").keyup(function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();

    $.post('search.php', { search_term: searchTerm}, function(data){

        $(".searchResults").html(data);
        $("#searchUl").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Again, everything else runs fine, but I don't know how to query multiple tables in a way so I can echo out the  href differently (i.e. index.php?band=$band_id for band and index.php?user=$user_id for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are losing information whether a record is a band or a user by doing a `UNION ALL`. This puts records of different types into the same set and merges the columns `band_id`, `user_id` and `band_name`, `username`.

You could fix this in different ways:

1. Create two separate queries. Then get all the results from the bands query and put them in an array and put all the results from the user query into a different array. Afterwards, echo the results of both arrays.
2. Make MySQL tell you the type of each row. You can achieve this by changing your query like this:

   ```
   (
       SELECT `band_id` , `band_name` , "band" AS `type`
       FROM `bands`
       WHERE `band_name` LIKE '%$search_term%'
       LIMIT 0 , 5
   )
   UNION ALL (    
       SELECT `user_id` , `username` , "user" AS `type`
       FROM `users`
       WHERE `username` LIKE '%$search_term%'
       LIMIT 0 , 5
   )
   ```

   Your query result will now have an additional column called `type` which will contain either `"band"` or `"user"`. Depending on the value of that column you can echo a different link.

   For example, you could extend your code like this:

   ```
   if($row["type"] === "band") {
       echo "somelink?band_id=" . $row["band_id"];
   } else {
       echo "somelink?user_id=" . $row["band_id"];
   }
   ```

   Note that in both cases you will need to read `$row["band_id"]` because the join will take the column name from the first part of the query. All user IDs will be in the `band_id` column.

Comment: How would I use the second option in an "if statement" or "echo" it out?

Comment: I ended up going with the first option, but I ended up having to put it through two different while loops causing it to display all band results before users. Not a good fix obviously, but it is nice to have it work. It will be perfected one day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MitchMullvain If using the second solution, you can access the type with `$row['type']`.

Comment: @MitchMullvain I updated my answer to include some example code how you could use the second solution; I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. It works beautifully now and your suggestion really reduced the code. I really appreciate your help.